# CSS card text changes/moves on animation

Tags: css, animation

I have this css card that I made:

https://codepen.io/octaviandd/pen/BaNPvrR?editors=1100

```
.card_front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.card_back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #07d697, #0ccfa3);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card_back p {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.68;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.card_back button {
  padding: 20px 50px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0.2rem 0.5rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

it's just a basic card flip but the problem I have is that when the animation is happening the text width is changing and it's positioning as well.

How can i repair this?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work for you if the font-family is specified in the card_back class?

```
.card_back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #07d697, #0ccfa3);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: "Sen", sans-serif;
}
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/gokuafrica/pen/yLNxyZq)